# Synology NAS insmod unknown symbol

Tags: networking, kernel-modules, nat, nas, synology

I'm trying to follow [this](https://galaxysd.github.io/linux/20170804/2017-08-04-iptables-on-Synology-DSM-6) guide to setup NAT on my Synology NAS. It worked great for me! I had everything working perfectly. But when I came back the next morning, the NAS had done a system update [DSM 6.2.2-24922]... The scripts were gone and after recreating them I get errors that the NAT kernel modules cannot be loaded.

Trying to isolate the issue with the insmod, I was able to determine which modules are failing, and see that it is because of "unknown symbols." Here's what I see (note that the variables here are defined in the script at the above link):

```
# for MODULE in ${KERNEL_MODULES_NAT}; do "${BIN_SYNOMODULETOOL}" --insmod "${SERVICE}" ${MODULE} || echo ${MODULE} = $?; done
nf_conntrack.ko = 1
nf_defrag_ipv4.ko = 1
nf_conntrack_ipv4.ko = 1
nf_nat.ko = 1
nf_nat_redirect.ko = 1
nf_nat_ipv4.ko = 1
iptable_nat.ko = 255
xt_nat.ko = 255
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4.ko = 1
xt_REDIRECT.ko = 255
ipt_MASQUERADE.ko = 255

# dmesg | tail -10
[ 2448.777252] iptable_nat: Unknown symbol ipt_alloc_initial_table (err 0)
[ 2448.784021] iptable_nat: Unknown symbol ipt_do_table (err 0)
[ 2448.789913] iptable_nat: Unknown symbol ipt_unregister_table (err 0)
[ 2448.796544] iptable_nat: Unknown symbol ipt_register_table (err 0)
[ 2448.818608] xt_nat: Unknown symbol xt_unregister_targets (err 0)
[ 2448.824851] xt_nat: Unknown symbol xt_register_targets (err 0)
[ 2448.862765] xt_REDIRECT: Unknown symbol xt_unregister_targets (err 0)
[ 2448.869368] xt_REDIRECT: Unknown symbol xt_register_targets (err 0)
[ 2448.891826] ipt_MASQUERADE: Unknown symbol xt_register_target (err 0)
[ 2448.898429] ipt_MASQUERADE: Unknown symbol xt_unregister_target (err 0)
```

I'm really not sure how to fix it. Maybe try to downgrade DSM? Maybe update the objects which are failing to load? Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to tag users, but I believe [this user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38666/galaxy) was the one who wrote that guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just installed a TinyCore Virtual Machine on the NAS which can handle the NAT. It seems a bit unnecessary, but I guess it's a little more controllable... so it works.